# How to create new folders and multiple new subfolders?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to create multiple folders and add multiple subfolders to these newly created folders. This is the sequence I believe the script should be executing:

Part 1. Create [folders](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zGUd_5loP44EkJnBj0cQ4KLnGvKKZtMO) and name them according to the folder names in column A of a [spreadsheet tab](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WVTxWvXqPIJ_S3D_ONjdZKuDDNlp8Ivtu0Wt_olMDM0/edit#gid=0) *(e.g., Folder 1, Folder 2)*. Folders with the same name will not be duplicated.

Part 2. Create multiple subfolders and name them according to the folder names in column B *(e.g., Fol A, Fol B)*. These subfolders are to sit inside the assigned Folder which was created in Part 1.
Example: Script creates Folder 2 from Part 1. It then creates Fol B and Fol C and puts them in Folder 1. [Tab Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQMYR.jpg)

Part 3. Duplicate a predetermined spreadsheet and insert it into the subfolders from Part 2.

I have tried writing a script for Part 1 and it works. But I am stumped with Part 2 and Part 3. Any advice or suggestion will be appreciated.

My code for Part 1:

```
/* Create new folder if same folder does not exist */
function createFolder(folderID, folderName){
  var parentFolder    = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var subFolders      = parentFolder.getFolders();
  var doesntExist     = true;
  var newFolder       = '';
  
// Check if folder already exists.
  while(subFolders.hasNext()){
    var folder = subFolders.next();
    
//If the name exists return the id of the folder
    if(folder.getName() === folderName){
      doesntExist = false;
      newFolder = folder;
      return newFolder.getId();
  };
};
  //If the name doesn't exists, then create a new folder
    if(doesntExist === true){
  //If the file doesn't exists
      newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(folderName);
      return newFolder.getId();
  };
};

function start(){
  var s               = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss              = s.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var folderRange     = ss.getDataRange();
  var folderRangeData = folderRange.getValues();
  var folderID        = '1zGUd_5loP44EkJnBj0cQ4KLnGvKKZtMO';

  Logger.log(folderRangeData)

  var noOfFolders = folderRangeData.length;
  Logger.log(noOfFolders)

for(var i=1 ; i<folderRangeData.length ; i++){
    if(folderRangeData[i][0] != ''){
    var folderName = (folderRangeData[i][0]);

//Call createFolder function
  var myFolderID = createFolder(folderID, folderName);

  Logger.log(myFolderID);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't ask questions because you want to know the answer. Ask questions because you want others to know the answer. No one will be trying to do exactly what you're trying to do. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions on this site should be specific. Considering this, please focus your question in only on part, show what you tried to write the script for that part, and add a brief description of your search efforts for question from this site as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I used this code with the following spreadsheet to create folders, subfolders and copy spreadsheets into the subfolders.

```
function makingfolders() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let root;
    if(r[0]) {
      root = DriveApp.getFolderById(r[0]);
    } else {
      root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    }
    if(r[1]) {
      let folder = root.createFolder(r[1]);
      if(r[2]) {
        let sfA = r[2].split(",");
        sfA.forEach(n => {
          let sf = folder.createFolder(n);
          if(r[3]) {
            let fi = DriveApp.getFileById(r[3])
            fi.makeCopy(fi.getName(),sf);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Sheet1:

| Parent folder Id | Folders | SubFolders | Spreadsheet Template Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| folderid1 | Name1 | NameA,Nameb,NameC | fileid1 |
| folderid2 | Name2 | NameA,Nameb,NameC | fileid2 |